# MATLAB function to swap two letters

Tags: matlab

Let's say I write a script that first asks the user to
enter a string.

Then, the script asks the user to enter two letter positions and eventually prints the new string with the two chosen letters swapped.

Here is an example of the execution:

**Please enter a string: I am studying in ASU**

**Please enter the index of the first letter: 3**

**Please enter the index of the second letter: 8**

**I um stadying in ASU**

What function do I use to swap the letters?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there isn't any built in function to do this. One method would be to utilize MATLAB's indexing to do the swap:

```
teststr = 'I am studying in ASU';

idx1 = 3;
idx2 = 8;

teststr([idx1 idx2]) = teststr([idx2 idx1]);
disp(teststr)
```

Which returns:

```
I um stadying in ASU
```

Comment: Easiest way to swap things. +1.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer @ko.dash by clicking the tick mark beside excaza's answer, Thanks!